# Добавить символ(строку) в char*

Tags: c++, char

Есть вот такое задание

**В отдельном модуле реализовать следующие функции:**

- int str_len ( char* s) – возвращает число символов в строке s без учета
  нулевого символа конца строки.
- char* str_n_cat ( char* dest, char* source, unsigned int num ) – присоединяет
  первые num символов строки source к строке dest, если длина строки source
  больше или равна num, или всю строку source, если длина строки source
  меньше чем num. Функция возвращает указатель на строку dest. Память для
  хранения строк source и dest выделяется за пределами функции. В случае
  невозможности выполнения операции по любым причинам, функция
  возвращает NULL.
  **При реализации данных функций нельзя использовать стандартные
  функции для работы со строками**

Второе задание решил выполнять таким образом:
Поместить в char dop первые num символов строки source, а потом с помощью конкатенации сложить dest и dop. Однако это не получается, так как появляется ошибка.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int str_len (char* s)
{
int x = 1;
int len = 0;

while(x)
{
    if (s[len] == 0) {x--;}
    else {len++;}
}

return len;
}

char* str_n_cat(char* dest, char* source, unsigned int num)
{
int count = 0;
char dop[num];

if (str_len(source) >= num)
{
    while(count < num)
    {
        dop[count] = dop[count] + source[count];
        count++;
    }
    dest = dest + dop;
}
}

int main()
{
char* s = "dest";
char* m = "source";

str_n_cat(s, m, 2);
}
```

Comment: У вас это не заработает. Сам принцип неверен — **куда** вы хотите дописывать символы? В какое место в памяти?

Comment: @Harry Вы имеете ввиду, что нужно создать новую переменную, и в нее помещать значения из dest и dop ? Объясните пожалуйста)

Comment: Нужна память, в которую вы можете писать. Массив какой-то, например, достаточного размера...

Comment: @Harry подскажите пожалуйста, как в данном примере выделить память для хранения строки. В условии указано, что память должна выделяться за пределами функции, а так же сама функция должна возвращать указатель на dest. Каким образом тогда сделать массив char достаточного размера, а так же, чтобы в нем уже хранились какие-то символы. Сначала думал в самой функции создать массив, но тогда решение будет не правильным

Comment: Раз за пределами функции, то как вы ее выделите — в локальном массива, или в динамической памяти — неважно. Важно, чтоб этой памяти было достаточно для размещения новой строки. Только вот при таких сигнатурах функций сделать это нереально, так что ответственность придется возлагать на программиста...

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string)

Answer (score 1):

Вобщем, я бы делал примерно [так](https://ideone.com/OoctWi):

```
unsigned int str_len(const char* s)
{
    if (!s) throw invalid_argument("nullptr in str_len()");
    unsigned int l = 0;
    while(*s++) ++l;
    return l;
}

char* str_n_cat(char* dest, const char* source, unsigned int num)
{
    if (!dest || !source) return nullptr;
    char * t = dest + str_len(dest);
    while(num-- && (*t++ = *source++));
    if (num == 0) *t = 0;
    return dest;
}

int main()
{
    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
    {
        char s[20] = "dest";
        char m[]   = "source";
        cout << "[" << str_n_cat(s, m, n) << "]\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант могу предложить  следующее:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;  
 //... код 
char* str_n_cat(char* dest, char* source)
    {
       string res = dest;
       res += source;
       return (char*)res.c_str();
    }
```

Comment: > При реализации данных функций **нельзя использовать стандартные функции** для работы со строками.

Насколько я помню, strcpy() относится к стандартным функциям, разве нет?

Comment: Спасибо  приму во внимание и попробую исправить

Comment: Функция возвращает указатель на объект, время жизни которого заканчивается при выходе из функции. Поведение приведённого кода не определено. [Тест](https://rextester.com/DRCC95716).

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем кто помог

Вот код функций, если кому-нибудь будет интересно

```
    int str_len (char* s) {
    int x = 1;
    int len = 0;

    while(x)
    {
        if (s[len] == 0) {x--;}
        else {len++;}
    }

    return len;
}

char* str_n_cat(char* dest, char* source, unsigned int num)
{
    if (!dest || !source)
        return nullptr;

    char* t = dest + str_len(dest);

    while(num--) *t++ = *source++;

    if (num == 0) *t = 0;

    return dest;
}

char* str_n_copy(char* dest, char* source, unsigned int num)
{
    if (!dest || !source)
        return nullptr;

    char* s = source;

    char* t = dest + str_len(dest);

    while(num--) *t++ = *s++;

    if (num == 0) *t = 0;

    return dest;
}
```